# How to implement AOP to set kafka offset to latest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement an Aspect so that Kafka read message from the latest offset.

I want to create and annotation like below:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

So if I use this annotation with any of the @KafkaListener method then this listener should read message from the latest one only.

I don't know how to write the AOP for this scenario.

Comment: why don't you set it through properties? and offset has nothing to do with `@KafkaListener`, this is something that need to be configured in configs, and by default offset is set to latest

Comment: Yes correct but I only want to do this for few KafkaListeners only, and also I want kafka offset to last message of topic, So latest does not help I guess. I don't know If messageListnerContainer help me or not.

Comment: it's not clear what you looking for, try to give an example, do you have multiple topics in same cluster and for some of them you need to set latest and for some of them you need to set earliest ? is that right?

Comment: yes correct I want to implement this use case. Actually this is for the testing purpose.

Comment: Example: If on one topic so many producers are using but if I start the server to run the test to read it from the topic so it takes time. thats why I want to read from the last offset for this topic.

Comment: how many topics are there totally? if there are less number of topics there one way to do this

Comment: Yes there are not so many topics,

Comment: create individual `Concurrent Listeners` for each topic with suitable configs, and offset is also related with group iid, better to add more info with clear example in post

Comment: I want to create aspect for this. We can get the offset by implementing ConsumerSeekAware and override onPartitionsAssigned and then we can call consumerSeekCallback.seek method.

But I don't want to implement this in every KafkaListener class instead I want to create a AOP for this and then I want to set Latest offset.